# Can "an implicitly-defined move constructor" be NOT trivial?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) defines "Trivial move constructor":

> The move constructor for class T is trivial if all of the following is
> true:
>
> - it is NOT user-provided (meaning, it is
>   implicitly-defined or defaulted);
> - T has no virtual member functions;T has no virtual base classes;
> - the move constructor selected for every direct base of T is trivial;
> - the move constructor selected for every non-static class type (or array of class type) member of T is trivial.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) also defines "Implicitly-defined move constructor":

> If the implicitly-declared move constructor is NEITHER deleted NOR
> trivial, it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and
> compiled) by the compiler if odr-used or needed for constant
> evaluation.

The implicitly-declared move constructor must NOT be deleted is obvious. But "it must NOT be trivial" sounds confusing to me.
Doesn't it mean that if it is NOT trivial then it should be "user-provided"? And if it already is "user-provided one" then why must "implicitly-declared one" kicks in?
So what wrong here? What is the point of an  implicitly-declared move constructor must NOT be trivial? Please help.

Comment: Note: cppreference, while very good and usually very accurate resource, is not standard. It's a user-curated wiki and there may be mistakes or inaccurate wordings.

Comment: "The move constructor selected for every direct base of T is trivial" is an easy way to get both. Suppose `BaseClass` has some user-defined move constructor. If `DerivedClass` inherits from `BaseClass` and doesn't write its own user-defined move constructor and relies on the implicitly-declared one, it will not be user-provided or trivial.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen oh. I didn't know that. thought it is the only reliable one :D

Comment: @NathanPierson well, i didn't expect it is that complicated. thanks for your help Nathan

Comment: That's just one possible way. Essentially, look at the definition for "trivial move constructor". It has four bullet points. You can make _any_ of the last three false while still having an implicitly-defined move constructor.

Comment: I think cppreference is just wrong here. I can't find anything the standard making implicit definitions of special member functions dependent on triviality.

Comment: does anyone has Creference phone number? I need to call them.

Comment: @user17732522 Have you found a definition in standard what "trivial copy/move constructor" actually means? I can see when copy/move constructor is trivial, but not what effect does it have. I did find the part that says defaulted function doesn't need to be defined until odr-used

Comment: @Yksisarvinen what is the original web to download C++ standard?  :D - is this one https://www.iso.org/standard/79358.html ? it costs money ? :)

Comment: @Rango No, the standard is not free. However, draft versions of standard are published for free in several places (and since drafts are published frequently as the work progresses, the most recent draft before standard publication is almost the same as the published standard). You can find most current work e.g. here: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ and PDF/HTML versions of drafts right before standard publication here: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/standards or here https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp. Beware, it's far from easy read. cppreference is almost always enough.

Comment: it's not free but it's also not  easy to read, not sure I want to buy it :D thanks @Yksisarvinen

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "_I can see when copy/move constructor is trivial, but not what effect does it have._": Well, "when" is the definition part. The effects are related to whether or not the type is trivially-copyable, whether or not some copy elision exceptions apply and whether or not the type is implicit-lifetime (and I might have missed some similar stuff).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "_I did find the part that says defaulted function doesn't need to be defined until odr-used_": Yes, that part is essentially the same as written in cppreference, but without the "trivial" part, which is why I am confused where the author got it from. As far as I know whether or not the constructor is trivial also has no effect on the one-definition-rule, nor on overload resolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Doesn't it mean that if it is NOT trivial then it should be "user-provided"?

No. If the constructor is user-provided, it cannot be trivial. But not being trivial doesn't mean it cannot be implicitly-declared.

> And if it already is "user-provided one" then why must "implicitly-declared one" kicks in?

I'm not sure what do you mean by this. A move constructor is either user-provided or implicitly-declared. If it is implicitly-declared, it can be trivial (if it meets more criteria).

Compare these two classes:

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    std::string b;
};
```

`A` has implicitly-defined and trivial move constructor. `B` has implicitly-declared, but non-trivial move constructor (because `std::string` has user-provided move constructor).

Both are implicitly-declared, meaning I didn't provide them, but they differ in implementation. Trivial move constructor needs not to be defined - that's the meaning of the second quote you provided. Compiler can simply replace it with `std::memmove` call. However, the non-trivial implicitly-declared move constructor must be defined (by the compiler) to call move constructors of each of the class members.

---

From yet another side, it could be presented like this:

- Move constructor

  - user-provided

    - deleted
    - non-deleted (user-defined)
  - implicitly-declared

    - deleted
    - trivial (std::memmove)
    - non-trivial (implicitly defined, when used in the code, will not be defined if not used)

Comment: Minor correction: trivial special member functions are also implicitly-defined. They're just defined to be trivial in some cases.

Comment: Between "user-provided" and "implicitly-declared" there is also "user-declared, but explicitly-defaulted" which is further subdivided into "explicitly-defaulted on its first declaration" and "explicitly-defaulted, but not on its first declaration". The former allows the constructor to also be trivial.

Comment: A trivial move constructor is not behaving like a memmove, except for unions. A memmove copies object representation. A non-union trivial constructor copies values. Also, as mentioned above both trivial and non-trivial implicitly-declared constructors are implicitly-defined when odr-used.